# Exception in Intellij's SBT Console: not found: value ideaPort ideaPort in Global := 49516

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

After a System Crash the `sbt-console` of *Intellij 2019.1* can not start:

The following Exception is thrown:

```
<set>:1: error: not found: value ideaPort
ideaPort in Global := 49516
```

Strangely another project just works fine.

I removed `.idea` with no success.

**Update**: Different ideaPort, same Problem /solution

```
<set>:1: error: not found: value ideaPort
ideaPort in Global := 53318
```

Answer (score 83, accepted):

I fixed by deleting the `<project base>/project/target` directory, as suggested here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-15160#focus=streamItem-27-3373132.0-0

On Terminal: `rm -r project/target`

Comment: This worked for me without needing to change the bytecode indices setting

Comment: I have followed all the steps above and it still hasn't helped. I wish I understood how this went from working to not working.

Comment: Ensure that you are actually deleting '/project/target' , and not the '/target' dir on the root of your project.

Comment: I figured out how to get `sbt-idea-shell` to work again (for me). If you are using `sbt-coursier`, you have to use the proper setting re: installed as the only plugin vs. installed alongside other plugins. It had been installed as "alongside other plugins" and after I changed the `sbt-coursier` plugin setup to "as the only plugin," then `sbt-idea-shell` started working again. See the `sbt-coursier` docs for detailed info on the different configurations.

Comment: Deleting `/project/target` didn't help me, but invalidating caches and restart did.

Comment: Today, deleting <projectbase>/project/target did help.

Answer (score 17):

Disable `Preferences` | `Build, Execution, Deployment` | `Compiler` | `Scala Compiler` | **Bytecode Indices** as a workaround.

Follow [this bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-15160) for the updates.

Comment: thanks - I tried to restart IntelliJ - and that helped as well.

Answer (score 6):

There is now even a simpler way that worked for me:

I got it from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60042492/2750966

> In my case, the reimporting of sbt project fixed the issue. This can
>   be done by clicking on the "sbt" tab on the right pane, right-click on
>   the project and selecting "Reimport sbt Project".

Or just hit the refresh button:

[image]