Value ideaPort not found
Running an SBT shell or any SBT command fails with
<set>:1: error: not found: value ideaPort
ideaPort in Global := 34497
^
[error] Type error in expression

I'm not sure which actions I did before this started appearing during builds. Issue does not happen to other team members building the same project. Issue doesn't happen on other projects which the same stack but slightly different versions of the stack. Issue persists after fresh project cloning.
We're using a pretty old SBT version 1.2.8 and I'm using bundled SBT that comes with IntelliJ on Ubuntu 22.04
I found couple of questions on this error, but none of the suggestions helped.
I tried:

removing <project base>/project/target and all modules
disabling Bytecode Indices
refreshing SBT project
removing .idea directory
reinstalling IntelliJ
installing older version of IntelliJ
cloning a project from the scratch
restarting the machine
switching IntelliJ SBT settings to use custom SBT I installed myself instead of bundled one
bunch of combination inside of SBT settings in IntelliJ

Probably some other things that I lost track of. Currently I'm exploring the option to upgrade SBT to 1.3.13, which doesn't throw this error, but I have some other issues.
Thanks for any type of suggestions and guidance!
EDIT: disabling Bytecode Indices resulted in
[error] Not a valid command: idea-shell (similar: shell, oldshell)
[error] Not a valid project ID: idea-shell
[error] Expected ':'
[error] Not a valid key: idea-shell (similar: daemonShell)
[error] idea-shell
[error]           ^

but only inside of IntelliJ, as a workaround I'm using sbt in terminal and it seems to work fine. I would like to return to IntelliJ for convenience.

Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55501899/exception-in-intellijs-sbt-console-not-found-value-ideaport-ideaport-in-globa help?

No it doesn't, as I listed in the question I tried all of the suggestions mentioned in that question. I should add other options that I tried meanwhile also, but it's still not working

I'm also experiencing this issue. It only seems to happen on one project but not on another. The only difference is that the project where it fails is running Java 11 and the other is Java 8 still. (Also SBT 1.2.8 due to project, Windows 11).

A potential workaround may be to use a "sbt Task" Run Configuration in IntelliJ (Untick "use SBT Shell"). This seems to let us run "clean" and "compile" tasks in the meantime.

@TonyDay that's a great workaround, thanks a lot!

I just got this resolved by colleague, he found suggestion on one of the tickets opened on JetBrains issue tracking. You just need to create plugins folder inside of ~/.sbt/1.0.
